# Thymeleaf compare #locale expression object with string

Tags: conditional-statements, locale, thymeleaf, spring-el

I want to set a th:class attribute depending on the context locale using the expression object #locale.

I have tried

```
th:class="${#locale}=='en'?'active':''"
th:class="${#locale=='en'}?'active':''"
```

Both of them results in false, but whent I print it with th:text="${#locale}, I got the correct locale code (en,es).

Any idea of how to compare the #locale object with a locale code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30501257/2229976) posted by [David_Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573750/david-garcia), I could resolve my issue this way:

```
th:class="__${#locale}__=='en'?'active':''
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a issue that I told to the guys of thymeleaf time ago.

You need to resolve first the `#locale` before comparing it with "en". 
You can do that adding  2 underscore at the beggining and end to the expresion that you want to resolve first. In your case will be something like this:

```
th:call="$({__#locale__}=='en'?'active':'')"
```

Comment: You where right about resolving the expression first, but the way you indicated did't work for me. I used this instead:
`th:class="__${#locale}__=='en'?'active':''` and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used like this

```
th:text="${#locale.toString()}=='in'?'active':'inactive'"
```