# Thymeleaf: Switch statement for a language selector

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm implementing a language selector with Thymeleaf for a Spring Boot project, but I can't get the variable ${#ctx.locale} working in the case statements. It takes always the default one ("*").

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav dropdown-toggle"
   id="languages" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

        <i class="material-icons">language</i>

        <div th:switch="${#ctx.locale}">
            <p th:case="en">English</p>
            <p th:case="es">Español</p>
            <p th:case="ca">Català</p>
            <p th:case="*">English</p>
        </div>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languages">
    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{?lang=en}">English</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{?lang=es}">Español</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{?lang=ca}">Català</a>
</div>
```

In fact, I just need the language name. Thank you.

Comment: Have you verified that ctx.locale is equal to `"en", "es", "ca",` etc in the view? If it is always getting to `"*"`, then it is probably not. Is that what you mean by "not working?

Comment: This code extract, belongs to a navigation bar, set into a fragment (<div th:fragment="navbar">). I've tested it, in one of the pages with the navbar, printing the text from: ${#ctx.locale}, and it shows the right locale (en, es or ca), but at the switch gets allways the default one (<p th:case="*">English</p>).

I've tested as well this other syntax <p th:case="'es'">Español</p> with the same result.

Comment: I've seen some examples where the case is enclosed in single quotes too. So `"'en'"` vs `"en"`.

Comment: Thanks Gregg, I've tried it as well, without succeeding either. I may be missing something, but I don't know what. 

Maybe I should consider switching to FreeMarker, now that I still in an early stage of the development.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The explanation is here: [thymeleaf-compare-locale-expression-object-with-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484119/thymeleaf-compare-locale-expression-object-with-string)

In your code change `th:switch="${#ctx.locale}" to th:switch="__${#locale.language}__"`

```
<div th:switch="__${#locale.language}__">
    <p th:case="en">English</p>
    <p th:case="es">Español</p>
    <p th:case="ca">Català</p>
    <p th:case="*">English</p>
</div>
```