# Thymeleaf: th:selected in a drop-down list

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to select an option of a Select Box based on the Locale Country but there s no way.
I've tried:

```
<option value="AR" th:selected="${#locale.country.contains('AR')}" >Argentina</option>
<option value="AR" th:selected="${#locale.contains('AR')}" >Argentina</option>
<option value="AR" th:selected="${__${#locale}__.contains('AR')}" >Argentina</option>
<option value="AR" th:selected="${#{__${#locale}__}.contains('AR')}" >Argentina</option>
```

This option shows the country (US)

```
<option value="US" th:text="${#locale.country}" th:selected="${#locale.country == 'US'}"  >United States</option>
```

But this option is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

The `#locale` expression returns the `java.util.Locale` object from the request, so you should be using the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for it:

```
#locale.country == `AR`
```

or if you prefer directly:

```
__${#locale}__=='es_AR'
```

By default, there is no method for `contains` in this object.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484119/thymeleaf-compare-locale-expression-object-with-string) may also help you in case you need to use `th:call`.