# Thymeleaf - getting locale and comparing

Tags: thymeleaf

The below should set h1 to HOWDY as the locale is showing en_GB, but it doesn't fall into the case?

Am I doing something wrong here?  Thanks

```
    <h1 th:text="${#locale}"></h1>
    <div th:switch="${#locale}">
        <h1 th:case="'en_GB'">HOWDY</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf compare #locale expression object with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484119/thymeleaf-compare-locale-expression-object-with-string)

Comment: Many thanks! Really appreciate that and yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Thymeleaf's `#locale`, you are using a reference to a Java [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) object.

**What Works?**

The following works the way you expect, because it has already evaluated the Java `locale` object to its string representation, before evaluating each `case` statement:

```html
<div th:switch="${#locale.toString()}">
    <h1 th:case="'en_GB'">HOWDY</h1>
</div>
```

The following also works:

```html
<div th:switch="__${#locale}__">
    <h1 th:case="'en_GB'">HOWDY</h1>
</div>
```

In this case, it works because you are using the Thymeleaf preprocessor syntax `__${...}__` to force Thymeleaf to evaluate `#locale` (to its string representation) before it evaluates the remainder of the `switch` statement.

**Additional Explanation**

Because Thymeleaf's `#locale` represents a Java `Locale` object, you can use any of `Locale`s suitable fields and methods, such as :

```html
<div th:text="${#locale.country}"></div>          <!-- a field -->
<div th:text="${#locale.toLanguageTag()}"></div>  <!-- a method -->
```

This is why only using `${#locale}` in the Thymeleaf switch statement does not match the `'en_GB'` string literal that you are expecting it to match: Thymeleaf is comparing an object to a string.

When you use this...

```html
<div th:text="${#locale}"></div>
```

...you are again accessing the object itself. But in this case the object will use its `toString()` method when being rendered by Thymeleaf, before it is displayed - giving you your `en_GB` displayed value.

However, when you use this...

```html
<div th:switch="${#locale}">
    <h1 th:case="'en_GB'">HOWDY</h1>
</div>
```

...Thymeleaf is using the locale object in the switch statement, not its string representation.